# Google Chart Tools Display in scrollable <Div>

Tags: css, html

I'm currently using the table in [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table.html) to display data I pull from a database. I then go ahead and display this grid inside a scroll-able div. As you can see on the attached screenshot, the column headings for some reason get wrapped to multiple lines, but I would like to have it display the column headings in only one line, not 3 or whatever else it wraps to...

[image: Screenshot]

And here is the CSS I use on the div:

```
.reportGrid {

   width: 1024px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 2px solid #ccc;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Does anybody have an idea why this would happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Add to your CSS class `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the column headings to not wrap, then the table must be wide enough to accommodate them.

You can truncate them with javascript dynamically if you have to.